# What size box do I need to splice 1-1-1-3 SER cable?

Tags: electrical

I have 1-1-1-3 copper SER cable that I need to transition to THHN to run through EMT.

I think I want to use insulated taps. What size box do I need?

Edit: more detail.
The SER will enter the box from the back. The THHN enters from the side via 1-1/4" EMT.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because it would be link-only or plagiarized. https://www.ecmweb.com/content/article/20892904/sizing-junction-boxes - sizing junction boxes for conductors this big is not trivial.

Comment: @KMJ That article is mostly about pulling wire through boxes. This question involves actual connections in the boxes.

Comment: The middle section is about boxes with splices (different math), and 314.28 applies to junction boxes as well as pull boxes. https://up.codes/s/pull-and-junction-boxes-and-conduit-bodies

Comment: You realize SER is allowed in conduit right? Provided the SER is not underground.  Also copper kinda sucks, if you're looking at it because you don't want terminal burn-ups, aluminum wire doesn't cause that, failure to use a torque screwdriver does.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the THHN is already in the conduit, but unfortunately it's a little short. The small run of SER will simplify going from the conduit to the box and save me hundreds of dollars in new wire.

Comment: @Matthew Reading your other questions it sounds like you're in a conduit pinch. can't use AL because of conduit fill on a conduit you can't replace. Been there myself... ouch.  Yeah, those Polaris connectors won't be cheap either.  I try to slide out of having to buy 4 Polaris connectors and an enclosure, by instead using a panel, disconnect or meter can :)

Comment: @Matthew what size is the conduit that has the THHN in it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's 1-1/4" EMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You'll need an 8" by 8" by 4" pull box for this

According to NEC 314.28(A)(2), splice boxes for 4AWG or larger wires need to be at least six times as long as the trade size of the largest conduit entering from that side.  For your 1¼" EMT, this means that our minimum size side-to-side is 7½", but they don't make boxes that size, so we round up to 8", and use a square box for this as that's going to be the easiest to find.  The depth is set by the rear entry due to the Exception in that code section that refers us to Table 312.6(A), which requires 3" for one 1AWG wire per terminal, which we round up to 4" due to box availability.

Note that you'll need to use something to bond the box.  This can be done using a suitable mechanical lug (such as an IHI S2-171 with the mounting hole drilled out to .203 for a #10 screw) attached to the grounding screw point in the box with a 10-32 machine screw and nut, then landing the grounding wire from the SER cable on it, or by using a Bridgeport 164 or equivalent grounding locknut on the EMT fitting then landing the SER grounding wire on that instead.